# Vector Resizing in C++ works only when adding cout statement?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<string> solution(vector<string> inputArray) {
    int n = inputArray.size();
    vector<string> outputString(n);
    int maxSize, curPos = 0;
    for(auto &i: inputArray)
    {
        int currentSize = i.size();
        if(currentSize > maxSize)
        {
            maxSize = currentSize;
            curPos = 0;
            outputString[curPos++] = i;
        }else if (currentSize == maxSize)
        {
            outputString[curPos++] = i;
        }
    }
    cout<<curPos;
    outputString.resize(curPos);
    return outputString;
}
```

In the original code without the *cout* line, the outputString resulted in an empty vector. But upon adding the cout line, the problem gets magically solved. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: You resize *after* you possibly go out of bounds of the `outputString` vector. Instead of initially setting a size, why not *reserve* memory instead, and then call `emplace_back` in the loop to add the strings?

Comment: `maxSize` is uninitialised so your code has undefined behaviour

Comment: The first time you use `maxSize` its uninitialized.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm pretty sure `curPos` can never be more than the size of the vector and the final resize shrinks it to just contain the valid values, reserve and emplace_back would still simplify the code though

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's why I said "possibly"... ;) And no, in this case it should not happen. But just the possibility and that it's not plain at a quick glance should, IMO, warrant a refactoring to improve that bit.

Comment: As an aside, unless you are planning to change the items in inputArray, pass it as `const vector<string>&` to avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxSize` is uninitialised so your code has undefined behaviour. UB produces surprising results like printing something changes the behaviour of the program.

By using `reserve` and then adding strings to the vector your code can be a lot simpler:

```
vector<string> solution(const vector<string>& inputArray) {
    size_t n = inputArray.size();
    vector<string> outputString;
    outputString.reserve(n)
    for(auto &i: inputArray)
    {
        int currentSize = i.size();
        if(outputString.empty() || currentSize > outputString.front().size())
        {
            outputString.clear();
            outputString.push_back(i);
        }else if (currentSize == outputString.front().size())
        {
            outputString.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int maxSize;
```

You declare `maxSize`, but not initialize it, so `maxSize` is uninitialized. And you use `maxSize` to compare with `currentSize` , which makes it undefined behavior.
Undefined behavior can do anything, so that's your problem.

Change to:

```cpp
int maxSize = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); // in <limits> header
```

Comment: It'd make more sense to initialise `maxSize` to 0 or even better change it to `size_t`